# jquery: this.not (':animated') && that.is (':visible') not following the rules, syntax problem? only few lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, visible, animated

when i click on `#button`, it's stilling doing the `'do something'`, even though `.wrapper` is animating and `.wrapper span` is not visible. so it's not following the rules. what's wrong?

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  if(
    $('.wrapper').not(':animated') && $('.wrapper span').is(':visible')
  ) {
    //do something
  }
})
```

Comment: `not(':animated')` is not a check but is a selector. so it will return `[]` if all `'.wrapper'`s are animated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a `working demo`:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
if(    $('.wrapper:animated').length>0)
{
 $(".wrapper").text("animating")   ;
}
  if(
    $('.wrapper:animated').length<1) {
 $(".wrapper").text("not animating")   ;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit cleaner without the if statements. [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ae5qP/3/)

```
$('#button').click(function(){ 
    $('.wrapper').filter(':animated').text("animating...");
    $('.wrapper').filter(':not(:animated)').text("not animating...");
})
```

​